# Method to extract Words from a sentence

Tags: java, regex

Im having a hard time at a at writing a method that extracts words from a sentence. The words should start with aAeEiIoOuU and are 5 letters long for example ether.

The method should return a String array.My problem here is that I want that the length of the array is the same as the foudn words. If it found 3 words the array length should be 3 too.

This is my code at the moment:

```
public static String[] extractWords(String text){
    String text = "einer hallo hallo einer";
    String pattern = "\\b[AaEeIiOoUu]\\p{L}\\p{L}\\p{L}\\p{L}\\b";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    int i = 0;
    while (m.find()){
        i++;

    }

    String[] array = new String[i];
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
        array[i] = m.group();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: Can you post what is the issue you're facing with the above code? Does it give wrong output? or something else?

Comment: When there are 2 words it found, the array length is 3 and not 2

Comment: Your second while loop is iterating over the exhausted matcher. You've to re-initialize the `Matcher` object, to again do `while (m.find())`. Or even better, you an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Why is this upvoted?

Comment: Have a look at [how to actually match Unicode letters and get your code working](http://ideone.com/KwiLsT).

Comment: use one while loop. add found work to Arraylist and then cast it to String[]

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ArrayList` here. To use array, you have to do the matching twice, which is unnecessary extra work.

Also, just so you know, the second `while(m.find())` loop, will not run even once, because the matcher has been exhausted by the first loop. You would need to re-initialize the `Matcher` object:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);  // Needed before second while loop.
```

But that is not needed. Let's use an `ArrayList` instead:

```
public static String[] extractWords(String text){
    String text = "einer hallo hallo einer";
    // Use quantifier to match 4 characters, instead of repeating it 4 times.
    String pattern = "\\b[AaEeIiOoUu]\\p{L}{4}\\b";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    List<String> matchedWords = new ArrayList<>();

    while (m.find()){
        matchedWords.add(m.group());
    }

    // If you want an array, convert the list to array
    String[] matchedWordArray = matchedWords.toArray(new String[matchedWords.size()]);
}
```